# Only permit one instance of a row with a particular column value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, conditional-statements

In my input array, I have multiple rows with a `userTag` of `All`, but I only want a maximum of one.  Other rows my have duplicated `userTag` values (such as `Seeker`), but extra `All` rows must be removed.

```
$input = [
    0 => ['userTag' => 'All', 'fbId' => 10210118553469338, 'price' => 70],
    1 => ['userTag' => 'All', 'fbId' => 10210118553469338, 'price' => 14],
    2 => ['userTag' => 'All', 'fbId' => 10210118553469338, 'price' => null],
    3 => ['userTag' => 'Seeker', 'fbId' => 10207897577195936, 'price' => 65],
    6 => ['userTag' => 'Seeker', 'fbId' => 709288842611719, 'price' => 75],
    17 => ['userTag' => 'Trader', 'fbId' => 2145752308783752, 'price' => null]
];
```

My current code:

```
$dat = array();
$dat2 = array();
foreach ($input as $key => $value)
{
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    if (count($dat) == 0) {
        $dat = $input[$key];
        $i++;
    } else {
        if ($input[$key]['userTag'] == "All") {
            if ($this->check($input[$key]['fbId'], $dat) == false) {
                $dat[$i] = $input[$key];
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            $dat2[$j] = $input[$key];
            $j++;
        }
    }
}
$data =  array_merge($dat, $dat2);
return $data;
```

The `check()` function:

```
public function check($val, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $vl) {
        if ($val == $array[$vl]['fbId']) {
             return true;
             break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so you want to remove duplicates of only  `userTag = All` yes?

Comment: yes i want to re move only userTag=All's duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code, **This will remove all duplicate values from your array**.

```
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $arr)));
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The updated answer below is the accurate solution asked in the question which helps with `All` rows data too.

```
$temp = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($val['userTag'] == "All" && empty($temp)) {
        $temp[$key] = $arr[$key];
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    else if ($val['userTag'] == "All") {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
$arr = array_merge($arr, $temp);
```

Comment: Because the `All` rows have different `price` values, comparing whole rows (as your first snippet does) will not work.  I recommend removing that part of your answer to avoid confusing researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa could you provide a code snippet where the first part is not working?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/gLhCM

Comment: @mickmackusa Got your point as per the question asked your updated answer can definitely help while my answer is to remove duplicates. Since the `All` rows have different values so those are not being removed. I am going to update my answer accordingly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try something simple like this:

```
$data = [];
foreach($input as $key => $value)
{
  $counter = 0;
  if($value['userTag'] =="All"){
       if($counter == 0 ) {//test if is the first userTag == All
          $counter = 1;//increment the counter so the if doesn't trigger and the value isn't appended
          $data[] = $value;//add it to the array
       }
   } else {
   $data[] = $value;//keep the rest of the values
   }
}
      return $data;
```

Comment: I want to remove All for One fbId Once then the 2nd fbId I wanna take userTag All Once and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. Perfectly working.

```
$n_array = array();$i=0;
foreach($array as $row){
    if($row['userTag']=="All"){
       if($i==0){
          $n_array[]=$row;
          $i=1;
       }
    }
    else $n_array[]=$row;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($n_array);
```

**Result**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userTag] => All
                [fbId] => 10210118553469338
                [fName] => Danish
                [lName] => Aftab
                [imageUrl] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/22491765_10210410024475931_8589925114603818114_n.jpg?oh=7fa6266e7948ef2d218076857972f7e0
                [subsType] => gold
                [user_visible] => 0
                [distance] => 0.01
                [advising] => 0
                [avgRate] => 4
                [totalReview] => 2
                [us_seeker_type] => new
                [price] => 70
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [userTag] => Seeker
                [fbId] => 10207897577195936
                [fName] => Saq
                [lName] => Khan
                [imageUrl] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/21151741_10207631130774942_8962953748374982841_n.jpg?oh=f5e5b9dff52b1ba90ca47ade3d703b01
                [subsType] => gold
                [user_visible] => 0
                [background] => 
                [topic] => 
                [distance] => 0.01
                [advising] => 0
                [avgRate] => 0
                [totalReview] => 0
                [us_seeker_type] => new
                [price] => 65
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [userTag] => Seeker
                [fbId] => 709288842611719
                [fName] => Muhammad
                [lName] => Hasan
                [imageUrl] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/20264704_681395725401031_2098768310549259034_n.jpg?oh=36db5b6ed60214088750794d4e3aa3e6
                [subsType] => gold
                [user_visible] => 0
                [distance] => 0.02
                [advising] => 0
                [avgRate] => 0
                [totalReview] => 0
                [us_seeker_type] => new
                [price] => 75
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [userTag] => Trader
                [fbId] => 2145752308783752
                [fName] => Jawaid
                [lName] => Ahmed
                [imageUrl] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/20992899_2068273703198280_4249128502952085310_n.jpg?oh=6df0be6ced405dd66ee50de238156183
                [subsType] => basic
                [user_visible] => 0
                [advising] => 0
                [distance] => 0
                [avgRate] => 0
                [totalReview] => 0
                [utr_trader_type] => new
                [price] => 
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep only the first occurrence of the `All` row, build an array where `All` is used as a first level key in the result array.  If the row isn't an `All` row, just keep using its original numeric key.  Using the `??=` "null coalescing assignment operator", you ensure that only the first `All` value is stored and all subsequently encountered `All` rows are ignored.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5GkKV))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    $result[$row['userTag'] === 'All' ? 'All' : $key] ??= $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

If you don't want to have the `All` key for later processing reasons, you can replace it by un-setting then re-pushing it into the array (after finishing the loop).

```
$result[] = $result['All']; // or unshift($result, $result['All']) to the start of the array
unset($result['All']);
```